# Python - How to plot data from multiple text files in a single graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I am trying to plot a graph by importing data from multiple text files in a single graph (multiple lines). For that, I wrote the following code:

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


filenames=glob.glob("FHGM3168-01G2-*#1.txt")


for f in filenames:
 print(f)
 data = np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=12)
 plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=100, frameon=True, clear=False)

 plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])
 plt.axis([-20000, 20000, -0.3, 0.3])

 plt.axvline(x=0, color="black", linestyle='-')
 plt.axhline(y=0, color="black", linestyle='-')


 plt.title("Test")
 plt.xlabel("Field (G)")
 plt.ylabel("Moment(memu)")

 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

The problem with the above code is I cant plot the data in a single graph. Because I am getting 50 individual graphs when I import 50 text files. Could someone please help me by correcting the code.

Comment: The best you can do is to read the documentation first, or at least watch a 10 minute youtube video on how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=100, frameon=True, clear=False)
plt.axis([-20000, 20000, -0.3, 0.3])

for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    data = np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=12)

    plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])

plt.axvline(x=0, color="black", linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=0, color="black", linestyle='-')

plt.title("Test")
plt.xlabel("Field (G)")
plt.ylabel("Moment(memu)")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. One more question how can I differentiate (legend titles) showing the multiple plots in a graph with their respective file name?

Comment: plt.legend(filenames). https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the graph outside the for loop (plt.figure() or the like). If you need plt.show(), do it after the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.